# Azure Webjobs: Does re-publishing associated website cause existing jobs to stop running?

Tags: azure, web, publishing, webjob

I have an Azure Website where I would like to be able to republish the website without stopping any webjobs that might be running in the background.

Ignoring the fact that it's bad practice to publish while the site is being used, this scenario means that a large queue might keep the webjobs firing 24/7 as load increases on the website.

I'm not sure if publishing the website (and not the webjobs) cause the webjobs (scheduled and on-demand) to cancel. Do they?

I think they do, and in that case, is there anything you can do to prevent that? I risk jobs being stopped halfway-through because of the need to publish, and I don't want to sit there waiting for the queue to be empty before publishing. A method of allowing currently running jobs to finish without starting new runs would be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

If the webjob files are not updated (under `wwwroot/app_data/jobs/...`) they will not restart.